# Docker Build from Source - How to Run?

Tags: docker

I wanted to have Docker 1.13.1 for use on ARMv8 and, with Docker (the organization) not yet providing an AArch64 build, I resorted to building it myself.

I followed a pretty good tutorial: http://oyvindsk.com/writing/docker-build-from-source

The result was that I pulled the source code from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/docker/docker.git
```

I switched to the repo and created a new branch from the v1.13.1 tag

```
cd docker
git checkout -b gta1.13.1 v1.13.1
```

I executed the two make calls:

```
make build
make binary
```

And sparing you some details, pushed the resultant binaries to a github repo of my own: https://github.com/scyentyfyc/docker

I then pull that repo down to a ARMv8 server that doesn't have docker installed yet, and I copy every file that doesn't end in .md5 or .sha256 over to /usr/bin, resulting in all of this in my /usr/bin

```
/usr/bin/docker
/usr/bin/docker-1.13.1
/usr/bin/docker-containerd
/usr/bin/docker-containerd-ctr
/usr/bin/docker-containerd-shim
/usr/bin/dockerd
/usr/bin/dockerd-1.13.1
/usr/bin/docker-init
/usr/bin/docker-proxy
/usr/bin/docker-runc
```

If I run dockerd manually, it seems to run ok, but I can't use the stuff I see suggested elsewhere like

```
service docker start
```

as I get the message, "Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found."  And when I attempt to use systemd

```
systemctl enable docker
```

I get the mssage, "Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory".

So, I'm just wondering what I'm missing.  I don't want to run the docker daemon manually, I want it set to run automatically on system start but after a great deal of wandering the interwebs I've come up empty handed

Comment: This should help: the "manually creating the systemd unit files" section of https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark is right. You're going to need to create service files so that systemd knows how to interact with the docker service. You'll need to copy the `.service` and `.socket files` in [this github repo](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/contrib/init/systemd) to `/etc/systemd/system`

Comment: Thank you very much.  This got me 90% of the way there.  I was still getting errors until I ran "groupadd docker" (I'm new to linux if that wasn't shining through bright and clear already... I have no idea what groupadd docker actually does).  This issue report on github is where I found that tidbit.  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29179.  Between the two of you, I'm golden!

Comment: groupadd docker makes your user part of the docker group which affects what files you have access to. Take a look at https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions to learn more.